# In Jasper Reports, has anyone tried excluding bands during text export?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've tried using the following property, but can't get it to work.

`<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.exclude.origin.band.1" value="title">`

I had also used 'txt' instead of 'text' as pointed out [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.%7Bformat%7D.exclude.origin.%7Bsuffix%7D.%7Barbitrary_name%7D), but it didn't work either.

Following is a sample jrxml with the above property -

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
   "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

<jasperReport xmlns = "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports
   http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
   name = "jasper_report_template" language = "groovy" pageWidth = "595"
   pageHeight = "842" columnWidth = "555" leftMargin = "20" rightMargin = "20"
   topMargin = "20" bottomMargin = "20">
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.text.exclude.origin.band.1" value="title"/>
   <queryString>
      <![CDATA[]]>
   </queryString>
   
   <title>
      <band height = "23">
         
         <staticText>
            <reportElement mode = "Opaque" x = "0" y = "3" width = "535" 
               height = "15" />
            
            <textElement />
            <text><![CDATA[This is title band]]> </text>
         </staticText>
    </band>
</title>    
   
    <detail>
      <band height = "16">
         
         <staticText>
            <reportElement mode = "Opaque" x = "0" y = "0" width = "535" 
               height = "14" backcolor = "#E5ECF9" />
            <textElement />
            <text><![CDATA[This is detail band]]> </text>
         </staticText>
      </band>
   </detail>
    
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: It is better to post small example to reproduce the issue

Comment: @Alex K, I've edited my post adding a sample code that includes the property